# Android phone camera is not recognising flat image targets : issues with license and database

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

Android phone camera is not recognising flat image targets. I created an application in unity using a vuforia plug-in. The build is made and it has been successfully installed on my android 12 phone. The camera is also on, but the camera is not recognising the image targets and hence I cannot see my AR layers.
When I enter game play mode in Unity and use my webcam, everything is working well and the markers are detected. Based on the suggestions given, I tried the identification with Android Logcat. And the errors seem to be between the license and database but I have no idea how to fix it. The screenshot of the logcat is attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6KXb.png)

I tried downloading the new vuforia plug in and tried changing the API specs, and changing the license and the database. But there was no difference.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would look at the logcat and check if you get some information on the problem https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html

Comment: Hi @emay Thank you for your message. I tried the Logcat that you mentioned. and this is what I got. it has been added as an attachment in the post. I would appreciate any and all help with resolving these errors.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here? https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/vuforia-license-manager